# JQuery Dynamically Created Draggable Div with Editable Text

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I'm trying to make small windows which are draggable and have editable divs inside using contentEditable=true.

I can drag them around but cant edit the text

```
   $(document).ready(function(){
    $('#mybtn').click(function(){
        $('#container').append("<div class=window><div class=bar>Story Element</div><div contentEditable=true class=textbox>Drag me</div></div>");
        $(".window").draggable({delay: 100});
    });

    $(".textbox").on("click", function(e) {
        $(".window").draggable('disable');
        $(this).find(".textbox").focus();
    });

    $(".textbox").on("blur", function(){
        $(".window").draggable('enable');
    });
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you make make the 'bar' class a handle for draggable, it looks like it acts how you want it to. You can drag the box around and still edit the text.

```
$(".window").draggable({handle:'.bar'});
```

http://jsfiddle.net/NrLgQ/

Answer (score 1):

You have not wrapped the attributes correctly for content you are appending.Try this:

```
$('#container').append("<div class='window'><div class='bar'>Story Element</div><div contentEditable='true' class='textbox'>Drag me</div></div>");
```

Comment: Thanks, but that is not the problem

Comment: @user3066347:what is the problem now.

Comment: The sloppy attribute wrapping is not causing the issue - I am not sure about how to go about creating draggable boxes with editable text.

Comment: can you create the fiddle

Comment: I am not sure what you are driving at.

Comment: Put all the code here at http://jsfiddle.net/ and share the link for saved fiddle.